# Show action on XML rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing, instance-variables

When in rails i would normally save records to a model and then if i want to show that individual record i would find that record by its id like so

```
 def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Then in my view i can show an attribute from that record like so

```
<%= @post.title %>
```

What i want to achieve is to show individual instances of data returned from an XML document, so if the xml document was like so

```
<entry>
 <id>xxx</id>
 <updated>xxx</updated> 
 <category  scheme="xxx"  term="xxx"/>
 <title type="text">xxx</title>
 <link rel="xxx" type="xxx"    href="xxx"/> 
 <link rel="xxx0gmail.com/b6ea0e8ddbc4e5"/>     
 <link rel="xx" type="xxx" href="xxx"/> <link rel="xx" type="axx" href="xxx"/> 
 <gd:email rel="xxx" address="xxx" primary="xx"/> 
</entry>
```

How can i have an action that say if i click on a link saying "view contact" how could i show that particular record?

At the moment i view all returned records like so

```
<% @mycontacts.each do |c| %>
<p> Name: <%= c.xpath('xmlns:title').text %>  Email: <%= c.xpath('gd:email/@address').text %> <%= link_to "Update Contact" %></p> 
<% end %>
```

which is parsed by Nokogiri

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open(url))
doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry[xmlns:title[node()]]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using some more xpath.

```
doc.xpath("//entry[id='xxx']")
```

This will return all the entries that have that specific ID (xxx in this case)

you can "imbed" information in a url by passing it to the link_to method

```
<%= link_to "show entry", :id => "xxx" %>
```

it will just be in the params hash

```
params[:id]
=> 'xxx'
```

Comment: you can read this: http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathpredicate.php as a good tutorial for xpath

Comment: Thank you, just thinking how would I grab current id of the returned attribute so to speak, so every record returned has a link that says view contact for example, I don't want to hardcore the id, so by clicking on the link it will take me to that particular record. Hope that makes sense

Comment: do you mean, how to get the id out the xml, or if you have the id, how to create a link that "contains" the id?

Comment: Create a link that contains the id, extraction I understand but it's almost as if I want to make that record an object but without saving it to a model

Comment: i updated my post, it should be something like this (i did not test it though)

Comment: so this should work even though i am not saving anything to a model?

Comment: @Richlewis i think so, you dont need your model for any of the mentioned code.